# inline CSS hack for ie6, ie7 and ie8

Tags: css, responsive-design

Does anyone know of a way to hide a single line of CSS to ie6,7 and 8 exclusively so that they simply don't see that line?

I'd like to be able to hide the a media query start and end so that those browsers just see what's inside the query.

I don't want to use conditional comments. It must be inline.

I know that sounds strange but I have my reasons! - If I have a mobile first cascade approach to my media queries but can show what's inside those queries to these browser then all modern browsers can be responsive but older browsers just get the final media query which in this case would be the desktop version.

thanks in advance!

Comment: To my knowledge you cant hide lines like that only individual rules or entire rule blocks (eg. `.some-selector {}`).

Comment: I thought that might be the case but worth a go.

Answer (score 4):

it's not “inline” but it doesn't use conditional comments... try simply with

```
@media all and (min-width:0) {
   /* your rules here */
}
```

you will target any modern browser and IE9

Comment: That's a great idea - but sort of the opposite of what I'm after. What I'd love to be able to do is show the contents of the media query to ie678 - that way they get the final media query which in this case would be my "desktop" version. - I know I could do that with conditional comments on the css file but I'd like to do it within the style sheet. I don't think there is a way to do this though. Thanks anyway!

Comment: mediaqueries are recognized on IE from version 9, so basically you can only declare all the needed style for IE6,7,8 before that mediaquery (seen by all browser) and the revert it after (IE>8 and all other browser).